# How to map query parameters to route parameters after GET-form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There is a simple GET-form on my page with one parameter (lets say `query`). If I submit form, it redirects me to `/Controller/Action?query=value`. I would like to be redirected to `/Controller/Action/value`.

How I can achieve that? URL rewrite mechanism? Something with routing configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You could use URL Redirect to implement that.Try to refer to my below demo:

1.Create a `RewriteRules` class

```
public class RewriteRules
{
    public static void RedirectRequests(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Query["SearchString"].ToString() != "")
        {
            var xx = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}/{request.Query["SearchString"].ToString()}";
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect ($"{context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}/{request.Query["SearchString"].ToString()}");
        }        
    }
}
```

2.Configure it as middleware in startup.cs

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
            .Add(RewriteRules.RedirectRequests)
            );
```

3.My view:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TestUrl" method="get">
<p>
    Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
</form>
```

4.My action:

```
[HttpGet("Home/TestUrl/{searchString?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestUrl(string searchString)
    {
        return Json(searchString);
    }
```

When you send `/Home/TestUrl?searchString=hello`, it will redirect to `/Home/TestUrl/hello` and return "hello".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you handle this with a Get request from javascript where you can handle the URL format to make a Get to the desired action method. By default the binding of a getform passes the parameter as part of the query string on the URL.
Before submitting the data get the data from the form and make a Get request via Ajax if you want passing the parameter to the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for WebApi routing configurations. If my guess is correct then you need to write this in your WebApi.config file in App_start folder.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
```

So based on the route request it will map with the corresponding route direction and it will take you to the particular controller and action method as per the request.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the parameter in a route template, and it'll do this for you. Given this example controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("something/{value}")]
    // -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is the route template.
    public IActionResult Something(string value)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

you can call `Something` with `/test/something/5` and `value` will be `5`.